# Problems with comunicate Turtlebot and Netbook

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
I am an engineering student who is working with the turtlebot, this one was purchased from the official website.

I  follow all the tutorials from the ROS website but, I think that ROS can't access my Create... Is not possible see informations about the robot in turtlebot_dashboard, like battery and sensors status, but is possible to see netbook battery status, then I can conclude that the connection Workstation-netbook is ok, the problem could be between the netbook and Create. The status of all sensors in turtlebot_dashboard is Stale, except the netbook battery.

Using  "lsusb" command, I can see that my converter is properly connected at ttyUSB0.

I read in another post that adding in the /etc/udev/rules.d/52-turtlebot.rules a line with my idProduct and idVendor the problem is solve. This line is:

ATTRS{idProduct}=="6001",ATTRS{idVendor}=="0403",MODE="666",GROUP="turtlebot"

But this don't work for me, can anyone help me?

Thanks, iscaram

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40307/problems-with-comunicate-turtlebot-and-netbook/) by [iscaram](https://answers.ros.org/users/2957/iscaram/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-08-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2012-08-01**:
Did you actually start the turtlebot?

**Comment by [iscaram](https://answers.ros.org/users/2957/iscaram/) on 2012-08-01**:
Yes, i have the turtlebot here, i did all the tutorials for install ROS (in both computers, turtlebot ones and in my laptop), but  Is not possible see informations about the robot in turtlebot_dashboard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had similar problems. When you run lsusb on TurtleBot laptop do you see a list of three microsoft corporation devices referring to the Kinect ?. If no, the TurtleBot is not fully up. Bring-up the TurtleBot either using minimal launch or service start and wait for the second beep from create. Now the dashboard should work properly. Put the TurtleBot on full mode and check lsusb again. This [post](http://answers.ros.org/question/29678/turtlebot-unstable/#29766) of mine might help.

---

Originally posted by [prasanna.kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2416/prasanna.kumar/) with karma: 1363 on 2012-08-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2